# IP-Sec VPN Tunnel Established Between 2 Remote Machines. Why Can't Machines In Their Subnets Connect Across?

Tags: vpn, ipsec, tunnel

Have 2 Remote Ubuntu Machines in different subnets.

1. one: 192.168.1.0/24
2. Two: 192.168.2.0/24

Established VPN tunnel between 2 machines, 1 in each subnet.

Their IPs:

Public IPs
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

Private IPs
192.168.1.100
192.168.2.100

After vpn is up, they both can ping each other's private IPs. Now want another machine, say with private IP: 192.168.1.150 ping machine on other subnet, say 192.168.2.100. But it doesn't work. I'm allowing all trafic via routes, NACLs and firewalls are disabled as well. What might be the issue??
need anything extra to configure on other nodes or something??

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about host/server configurations are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

Basically is missing the routers to reach the other networks, on the hosts of network one you need to add a route to network two on the private IP 192.168.1.100, and do the same for the other network, also may be you need to enable forwarding on the routers 19.168.1.100 and 192.168.2.100.